# What is this issue, and how to prevent by jQuery's own way?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am implementing a append operation using `$.each` - method. the result is funny(getting double the time of elements!). I may have some workaround to fix this.

But I want to understand the real issue here, as well is there a way to fix this using `jQuery`'s own way?

Thanks in advance.

```js
var data = ["orange", "apple"];
var temp = function() {
  var template = '<dl class="dropdown"><dt> <div class ="dropdownclass" ><span class="hida">Select</span> <span class="multiSel"></span>  </div></dt><dd><div class="mutliSelect"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="Control" />Control Node</li><li><input type="checkbox" value="Border" />Border Node</li</ul></div></dd></dl>';
  return $(template).clone();
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  var tr;
  var ut
  $.each(data, function(i, value) {
    tr = $('<tr />', {
      id: i + 'id'
    });
    ut = temp();
    ut.addClass('hema' + i).click(function() {
      alert($(this).prop('class'));
    });
    tr.append(ut);
    tr.appendTo('tbody'); //getting multple instance!!!
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>title</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Take a look at your elements pane in dev tools, you have two `<tbody>` elements because some browsers will auto fix improper html, ie a `<tr>` directly inside a `<table>` is improper, it has to be in a `<tbody>` (or thead/tfoot) so it makes an extra one, and your `appendTo` appends to each tbody

Comment: when i console, i am getting exactly 1 value on each time

Comment: when you have a tr it should be either inside tbody or thead if its not browser will automatically wrap it in a tbody so there will be two tbodies in the table and when you do appendTo to it will be appended twice.

Comment: so, according to you people, do i require to delete the `tbody` - ?

Comment: no need either wrap the tr inside the tbody or if its a header row for the table keep it inside thead.

Comment: The messages are not being duplicated in the console since the each is doing only one round of iterations. The duplication occurs when you do the appendTo('tbody');

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is simply because your HTML is invalid. Your `tbody` must encompass *all* `tr` elements. Because you had a `tr` outside of the `tbody` the HTML renderer added a second `tbody` around that - you can see this if you check your original snippet in a DOM inspector. Hence when you appended to `tbody` the content was duplicated across both elements.

If you fix your HTML, the problem goes away:

```js
var data = ["orange", "apple"];
var temp = function() {
  var template = '<dl class="dropdown"><dt><div class ="dropdownclass" ><span class="hida">Select</span> <span class="multiSel"></span>  </div></dt><dd><div class="mutliSelect"><ul><li><input type="checkbox" value="Control" />Control Node</li><li><input type="checkbox" value="Border" />Border Node</li</ul></div></dd></dl>';
  return $(template);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $.each(data, function(i, value) {
    var $tr = $('<tr />', {
      id: i + 'id'
    });
    var $ut = temp().addClass('hema' + i);
    $tr.append($ut).appendTo('tbody');
  })

  $('tbody').on('click', '.dropdown', function() {
    alert($(this).prop('class'));
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <!-- note tbody here -->
    <tr>
      <th>title</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Note that I made a couple of amendments to your JS logic too; there's no need for the `clone()` as you're creating a new element anyway, made the var declarations local to the `each` loop and used a single delegated event handler instead of attaching one to every element in the loop.